# If $f$ reduces $L_1$ to $L$ and also $L_2$ to $L$ is $L_1=L_2$

Tags: computability, reductions

If the *same* $f$ reduces $L_1$ to $L$ and also $L_2$ to $L$ does it imply that $L_1=L_2$?

My intuition says no, but I couldn't find a counterexample.

Comment: Hint: There is a very concise way to express $L_1$ using $f$ and $L$. The same for $L_2$. Check the [definition of reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction#Formal_languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition of reduction,

$x\in L_1\iff f(x)\in L \iff x\in L_2$

And thus $L_1=L_2$.

Answer (score -2):

When a reduction takes place that means that the problem $L_i$ is just a different "point of view" of problem $L$. Given that you have two problems $L_1$ and $L_2$ reducible to the same $L$ then you could say that by solving $L$ you would be able to solve both. This in turn implies that they could be treated as the same problem.

Comment: This is **not** true. Every language in Exp has a reduction to some very hard problem in Exp,, but there are languages that require a poly time turing machine and others that require an exponential time turing machine. Obviously, they are not the same.

Comment: The OP however asked what would happen if the reduction function is the same. Its a bit different in this case.